# Angular2 - How to share css file data with another css file

Tags: angular

I have app.component.html file that has html header and also  where i put my router html template changes. 
Html header is shared between 2 other components - home.component.ts and product-list.component.ts. 
What i would like to do is somehow being able to change app.component.css data through product-list.component.css file, when user goes to  /product-list page.

So when user goes to /product-list page, the html header that is shared between many pages needs to have border-bottom added. Can anyone help?

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="" class="header-container clearfix">

        <div class="logo"></div>
            <p class="header-tekst">          
                TITLE
            </p> 
        <div class="logo2"></div>

    </a>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**product-list.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent {

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routingComponents } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponents
  ],
  imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     FormsModule,
     HttpModule
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.css**

```
nav a.active{
    color:red;
    background:blue;
}

nav a{
    padding:10px;
    background:grey;    
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}

nav li{
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
}

  .header{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
  }


  .header-container a{
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .header-tekst{
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color:#0356a0;
  }
```

**product-list.component.css**

```
#wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 46px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding-top:46px;
  background-color: white;
}
   .header{
        border-bottom:2px solid grey;
   }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list.component';


const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
        //{path: '', redirectTo: '/kodu', pathMatch:'full'},
        {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
        {path: 'product-list', component: ProductListComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
export const routingComponents = [HomeComponent, ProductListComponent]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the question you want to change the header css in app.component.html when user goes to different pages. So you can do this in app.component.ts

```
import { Router, NavigationStart, ViewChild } from "@angular/router";
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("myHeader") myHeader;
  constructor(public router: Router) {
    router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (event.url === "/product-list") {
          // fill the styles whatever you like
          this.myHeader._elementRef.nativeElement.style.borderBottom = "";
          this.myHeader._elementRef.nativeElement.style.borderBottomColor = "";
          this.myHeader._elementRef.nativeElement.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "";
          this.myHeader._elementRef.nativeElement.style.borderBottomRightRadius = "";
          this.myHeader._elementRef.nativeElement.style.borderBottomStyle = "";
          this.myHeader._elementRef.nativeElement.style.borderBottomWidth = "";
        }
      }
      // NavigationEnd
      // NavigationCancel
      // NavigationError
      // RoutesRecognized
    });
  }
}
```

You should add #ID to your header like this;

```
<div class="header" #myHeader>
    <a href="" class="header-container clearfix">

        <div class="logo"></div>
            <p class="header-tekst">          
                TITLE
            </p> 
        <div class="logo2"></div>

    </a>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You can also use jquery after finding your header

```
$(this.myHeader._elementRef.nativeElement).css({border-bottom: ""});
```

EDIT: Another solution, you can also use ngClass in your header html

```
<div class="header" [ngClass]="{'routed-page-css': router.url === '/product-list'}">
    <a href="" class="header-container clearfix">

        <div class="logo"></div>
            <p class="header-tekst">          
                TITLE
            </p> 
        <div class="logo2"></div>

    </a>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and then add css

```
.routed-page-css {
  border-bottom: "whatever you want"
}
```

EDIT: Import router and inject it in contructor

import { Router } from "@angular/router";
constructor (public router: Router) {}

Comment: First answer gives me error: Cannot find name 'ViewChild'.

Comment: Second answer gives me error: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: For first answers error you should import ViewChild like; 
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

Comment: for second answer Import router and inject it in contructor

import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

constructor (public router: Router) {}

Answer (score 0):

You should set view encapsulation to none in your product-list.component.ts.
Follow this link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#view-encapsulation